# After login it redirect to previous page but it's not logged in

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

i used this for after login redirection previous page

***System > Config > Customer >Custumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO***

It's working fine. But my problem is

First i login it redirects to home page but top link still showing login only after refresh my browser does it change to logout

if i set

***System > Config > Customer > Customer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > yes***

it's working fine redirect to my account page and top link changes to logout

How do i fix it?

Comment: tried it with CE 1.9.2.1 - Rwd Package/Theme and worked fine. Seems like you are using a different Package/Theme which doesnt support this feature.

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 rwd

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 rwd/my theme why it's not working

Comment: Might be some issue with full page caching, do you have it ON ?

Comment: do you mean full page cache module enable or not right